# Using php to generate html pages?

Tags: php, html, dynamic, static

Quick question, I am working on a project at work and I would like to ask if the following is possible, and some tips to get started on it:

I have a index.html, and 001.html, 002.html, 003.html that get loaded in it with jQuery(.load() technique).

I would like to generate pages with a php file, a backend if you prefer, I would have 98% of the code that stays the same, but some data fetched in the SQL database (image001 for example).
Once that is generated I would like to edit the index.html page to add the page generated in it.

Is this possible ?

Thanks in advance !

(you could also look at the code here: www.ca-cest-fait.fr if you want to understand better).

Comment: Of course this is possible, that is the whole meaning of php... .

Comment: @Gernot: You seem to miss the point. He wants to generate the HTML page, save it on the server, then edit the main index.html to include it as well. It's possible, but very not recommended.

Comment: Ahh, sorry... . I thought he wanted to know if it is possible to generate dynamic html pages - so, pages with embeeded php. Sorry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are attempting is very not recommended. It is the wrong approach. The correct approach is to `jQuery.load()` a `.php` file, which would **dynamically** generate the correct response, and be included in the page. This saves you the trouble of generating and saving endless pages on the server.

---

It is however, possible. Using `glob()` you can find out what current files exist. Using `fopen()` and `fwrite()` you can write a file, or if you like being fancy, you can use `DOM` to generate the HTML for you.

Then, you use the same techniques to edit the `index.html` file, to include the newest files.

> Note, this method is a *huge* hussle and shouldn't be done.

Comment: Thanks for the info.

The main reason why I use .load is to get less images, per html file we upload maybe 30+ images and are using a slider made for mobile phones that seems a bit heavy.
So what happens is when I click on a div I get 001.html containing the slider + images, 002 unloads that and gets the new one, only to make the whole thing faster.

Thanks for your tips on glob() and fopen() though, I will have a look into it and see if I an find a different way to do this.

Comment: I wouldn't recommed this approach. It would make your markup very *very* weird, and even unusable in older browsers.

Comment: Agreed with great sage madara. What i am confuse here is, how serving an html file will make it faster than a dynamic output?